# C++ volatile object constructed with placement new

Tags: c++, concurrency, x86

I am using placement new to construct an object that lives somewhere in memory (e.g. memory mapped IO):

```
struct alignas(16) A
{
    std::uint32_t m_i;
};

...

A* pA = new (memArena) A();
```

In my consumer code, I have several branches on `m_i`. Am I correct to think that it has to be marked as `volatile` otherwise the compiler might store it in a register and the branch would check this register instead of the value stored in memory?

At the moment I don't have it marked as `volatile`, but uses compiler fence such as `asm volatile("" : : "i,r,m"(m_i) : "memory");`, is this enough?

I am only interested in  x86 here, not any other architecture. Also, there is one process writing to this memory area and another one consuming, but my question is not about concurrency issues, only about the potential mistakes coming from my compiler's optimizations.

**Edit**: fixed placement new syntax, changed *class* to *struct*

Comment: *Am I correct to think that it has to be marked as volatile* - no, it should be `std::atomic`.  C++11 has been around for almost a decade, rolling your own `memory_order_relaxed` using `volatile` is silly.  See [When to use volatile with multi threading?](//stackoverflow.com/a/58535118)

Comment: @PeterCordes The question also mentions that the location of the variable is memory-mapped IO for which I think `volatile` is a valid use case, isn't it?

Comment: @walnut: I just noticed that it was actual MMIO :P  But it's also read/written by multiple processes, so this is a use case for `volatile std::atomic<uint32_t> m_i;`  (which in practice will compile to identical machine code as plain `std::atomic<uint32_t> m_i` (because compilers don't optimize atomics), and if you use `mo_relaxed` also to identical machine code to plain `volatile m_i`.   (Or minor differences because of compiler quirks, like gcc not using `volatile` objects as a memory source operand.)

Comment: And BTW, `asm` memory barriers can be ok for concurrency if you're careful and know the asm memory model, but not for MMIO.  That wouldn't stop the compiler from e.g. reading memory twice when the source reads it once, which is not ok if reads have a side effect.

Comment: @walnut thanks, I wrote this a bit too quickly, fixed the syntax.

Comment: @PeterCordes I am not using `volatile` to roll my own `memory_order_relaxed`, I am using `volatile` to avoid that the compiler keep my variable in a register. `volatile` does not guarantee anything when it comes to atomicity, this is done by my aligned `int32_t`, what Intel guarantees, and my usecase. I guess the only interesting addition that `std::atomic` guarantees is that my store to the `int32_t` is in one instruction, not multiple... About the memory barrier, it's not about concurrency, it's a compiler fence to avoid instruction reordering.

Comment: A compiler barrier can sometimes work, but simply making the object `volaitle` is better for MMIO: you want every access in the source to result in exactly one access in the asm.  `int tmp = *mmio_pointer` could compile to multiple loads if you use `tmp` multiple times.